# Hide red5's context path (or Flash Media Live Encoder's FMS URL)

Tags: flash, media, live, red5, encoder

Is it possible to stream a webcam image via Flash Media Live Encoder to red5 (for example: rtmp://127.0.0.1/**mySecretStreamInput**) and make it available for clients on another URL (something like: rtmp://IP_ADDRESS/**stream**)?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The keyword you are looking for is 'proxy' or 'proxying'. I'm not sure what you intend to do with this but keep in mind though that the only thing being hidden is the source url; it would not help to protect your content as the new url would serve the very same content.